# @WebServlet("/category/*") Annotations with *, the servlet does not load the html images in tomcat 9

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, tomcat9

```
@WebServlet("/category/*")
public class Product extends HttpServlet { .......
...........

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        response.getWriter().append("<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n" + 

                "<html lang=\"es\">\r\n" + 
                "<head>\r\n" + 
                  <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />\r\n" + 
                "</head>\r\n" + 
                "<body>\r\n" + 

                "<div ><figure><img src='image/img4.jpg'></figure></div>\r\n" +

                "</body>\r\n" + 
                "</html>");
    }
```

The question is, when putting the * in the paths in the notations as well as in web.xml, the images don't load, but if I remove the * and put the product name in its place, everything works correctly. The images are in the root directory of the application. I have tried with absolute path and neither. I don't understand why this happens, any help please.

That's right, thanks stdunbar.
 @WebServlet ("/ category / *"), I already have it fixed. It was just putting "../" ../images/img4.png.
Now the problem is when I put @WebServlet ("/ *"), even putting the path "http: //domain/project/image/img4.png" the browser does not mark any error but does not show the image.
With @WebFilter ("/ *") the same thing happens.

I have managed to load the images in two ways:

1. from the Filter or a servlet, leaving the container and re-entering with response.sendRedirect ("http: // domain / project / product"), since with request.getRequestDispatcher ("product"). Forward (request, response) also does not load the images, which should be correct since it does not come out of the container and is more efficient.
2. putting a path to another project that contains the images
   "http: //dominio/proyecto-image/image/img4.png".

Is there a way that images can be loaded as it is done when there is a servlet with static path @WebServlet ("/ product")?
Since this is more efficient than when I use the two mentioned. If you make a new request and go to another project, you can see that the loading of images has a delay.

The thing is that with / * there is no way to load the images I have in the same project.

Comment: I'm guessing you're getting a 404 on the images as the browser now wants to load `/category/something/images/img4.png`, correct?

Comment: The fact is that with / * there is no way to load the images that I have in the same project